# MySQL: adding a string with a comma to an existing field

Tags: mysql

In my Users table I have a row called "products_in_sale" that contains the product ids of the products the user sells.

For one user it looks like this. "33" <-- therefore this very user sells only one product with the id `33`.

Now, since users can sell more than one product, I have to join another number (preferably with a "," in between) to this field when a user creates a new product.

How does the necessary `UPDATE` statement have to look?

maybe `'UPDATE Users SET products_in_sale = products_in_sale + ", '.$id.'"';` ?

thanks for your help!

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. Don't do this. Never store multiple values in a single column. Add another table to make the relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function:

```
UPDATE Users SET products_in_sale = CONCAT_WS(',', products_in_sale, newProductId) where userId = ?
```

This query should work also for the first insert, if your `products_in_sale` column defaults to `NULL`.

Anyway, as suggested by juergen, using another table would be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Never never store multiple values in a single cell, this is a violation of first normal form (1NF). Read more: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html

Every value (e.g. product_id) should have its cell in a relational database table. In your case, there should be a table say "user_product" with at least 2 fields - "user_id" and "product_id", and both are composite primary key. 
Of course, there should be a "user" table storing user details which would have a "user_id" field linking to the "user_id" field of the "user_product" table. Likewise, there should be a "product" table storing product details which would have a "product_id" field linking to the "product_id" field of the "user_product" table.